# Views, Views-Slideshow, and Paging in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views, paging

The situation is as follows:  I have a content type Slide, and I want to display the three newest slides in a slideshow.  The slides need to cycle, and the slides also need to be controllable by a pager.  The pager should have three bullets/links/images to be able to jump to a particular slide in the slideshow.  The pager should also have left and right arrows for incrementing and decrementing the the slide in the slideshow.

This technique is used ubiquitously around the web, yet I can't seem to figure out how to set this up correctly using Views and Views Slideshow.  Any pointers from all of you experienced Drupalites out there are welcome.

Cheers, Les.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(1) Required Modules (Version: Drupal7.0)

```
Views
Views Slideshow
Chaos tool suite
Libraries
Link Field
Token
```

(2) Install the Modules

In Drupal7 you can install modules from the admin section, but I still feel this new feature doesn't have any meaning, because we have to search for the module link in the Druapl site and then copy paste into the admin module installation area, really crazy. It would have been so good if they would have made it something like wordpress a small search feasture. Anyway I just gonna download and istall it in the old way (I still recommend this old way).

Download all the modules from Drupal site and install in the directory yoursitename/sites/all/modules.
Go to http://www.yoursitename.com/node#overlay=admin/modules and enable these modules as below;

(1) Views (2) Views UI (3) Views Slideshow (4) Views Slideshow: Cycle (5) Chaos tools (6) Link (7) Libraries (8) Token (Optional)
(3) Create Image Cache

In Drupal7 imagecache is part of core module and is named as Image styles. So let's create two image cache from here, one for the full size slider image and other for the thumbnail image. In this tutorial I use 935x293 (pixels) dimension for the full size slider image and 210x100 (pixels) dimension for the thumbnail image. Note: These configurations csn be defered depends on your needs.

- Fullsize Slider image settings

Go to http://www.yoursitename.com/node#overlay=admin/config/media/image-styles and click on the add new style link
  (1) Give an Image style name and click on create new style button
  (2) On the next configuration screen select new style you want and then click add button (In this tutorial I choose resize style)
  (3) On the next screen set the width and height and click on the add effect button. (The settings may vary depend on the style you choose). I set width as 935 and height as 293 pixels.

Do this same process for the thumbnail image too. (for the thumbnail image dimension, I set width as 210 and height as 100 pixels.)
(4) Create New Content Type

Let's create a new content type, From the dashboard menu bar cick on Structure and then content types then click on the add new content type link.

(1) Give a human-readable name, I named it as Featured Slider (machiine name will be auto generated based on the human readable name)
  (2) Give a brief and relevant description
  (3) Submission form settings, I leave as the default settings
  (4) Publishing options, I checked only published (all other settings unchecked)
  (5) Display settings, I have unchecked the authour and date info.
  (6) Comment settings,I set hidden (disabled)
  (7) Menu settings, I leave as default settings.
  (8) Click Save and add fields Button
(5) Create New Fields

Here in this example I create only two fileds, and they are image field and link field.
We will use image field for uploading our slider image and link field for creating a custom link where we want our slider to be linked.

Image Field Settings

```
(1) Label: Slider Image
(2) Field: slider_image
(3) Field type: image
(4) Widget (form element): image
(5) Click Save button, and on the field settings page leave default settings and click on Save field settings button.
(6) On the image field configuration settings page you can configure as you wish.
```

I set this field as required, I added a file director name called slider-image so that this images will be arranged sperately from other images.
You can set the maximum upload size and resolution here, I have anabled alt and title field and finally click Save settings button.

By using same method create the link field too.

Link Field Settings
    (1) Label: Slider Link
    (2) Field: slider_link
    (3) Field type: link
    (4) Widget (form element): link
    (5) Click Save button,
For the link field configurations leave evrything to default settings.
I have re arranged the field like shown below;
 Title field
 Image field
 Link field
 Body field (you can even remove this field if not necessary)
Manage Display
On the manage display tab you can conigure how the out put of the field to be diplayed.
I have set the link field as hidden and I have also set image label as hidden
Drupal7: manage fields
(6) Create Feature Slider Content

I have created four featured slider content for this tutorial.

(1) Click on add content link
  (2) Create Featured Slider content
  (3) Give a proper title name
  (4) Upload slider image
  (5) Give alt and title field names
  (6) Give a link title and url where you want the slider to be linked
  (7) Leave all othe settings as default except for the path field if yo want you can give an SEO friendly URL alias.
  (8) Save the content.

Same way create more Featured Slider contents (I have created four contents)
(7) Create a New View

Now it's time to create our new Slideshow view.
From the Dashboard menu click on the Structure and then click on the Views.

(1) Click add new view link
  (2) Give view name, I have named as Featured Slider (machiine name will be auto generated)
  (3) Give an apropriate view description
  (4) Choose Show Content of type Featured Slider (your content type name).
  (5) Uncheck Create a Pge and check Create a block
  (6) Type in Block title and choose display format as "Slideshow" of "fields" items per page 5 (you can enter the number of items you want to display)
  (7) Click the button "Continue & edit"
Views Field Settings
First let's add link field (link must be the first field in order to work everything properly) so click on the add icon and from the filter Groups select Content
Add Content: Link, Click "Add & configure button" in the next cofiguration window uncheck "Create a label". "Check" Exclude from display.
Click "Apply button"

Next let's add image field, so click on the add icon and from the filter Groups select content
Add Content: image field (Note: make sure you choose the image field which we crerated for this slider content type only.)
Click "Add & configure button" in the next cofiguration window uncheck "Create a label".

Formatter: Image (if you have installed Colorbox or lightbox you can choose them here!)
Image Style: Fullsize (Choose the imagecache you have created in the above step)
Link image to: Nothing
Style Settings: Leave default settings
No result behaviour: Leave default settings
Rewrite Results: Check Output this field as a link
Link path: [view_node] (Note:Scroll dow a bit and you can see replacement patterns created by Core Token module, (if we didn't set the link field as first we can't see link field option here) copy only [view_node] then scroll up and paste it in the link path field.)
Click "Apply button"

Finally we need one more field for the thumbnail, so let's click on the add icon and from the filter Groups select Content
Add Content: image field (Note: make sure you choose the image field which we crerated for this slider content type only.)
Click "Add & configure button" in the next cofiguration window uncheck "Create a label" and CHECK EXCLUDE FROM DISPLAY,
Formatter: Image (if you have installed Colorbox or lightbox you can choose them here!)
Image Style: Thumbnail (Choose the imagecache you have created in the above step)
Link image to: Nothing
Style Settings: Leave default settings
No result behaviour: Leave default settings
Rewrite Results: Check Output this field as a link
Link path: [view_node] (Note:Scroll dow a bit and you can see replacement patterns created by Core Token module, (if we didn't set the link field as first we can't see link field option here) copy only [view_node] then scroll up and paste it in the link path field.)
Click "Apply button"

Views Filters Settings

In views3 the filters are created in the beginning while we choose the content type and other settings! If you need any additional filetering you can create it here!

Views Style Settings

Click on the Format Slideshow | settigs and on the next configuratioin window set as below;
  (1) List type: Unordered list
  (2) Wrapper class: Leave default settings
  (3) Style> Skin: deafult
  (4) Slides> Slideshow type: cycle
  (5) Cycle options
You need to download jQuery cycle plugin and copy jquery.cycle.all.min.js to sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle You can find the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle.

IN SIMPLE ENGLISH
Create a folder named "libraries" in the site/all directory and then create an another folder named "jquery.cycle" in that directory and finally copy and paste only the "jquery.cycle.all.min.js" into this directory.

(6) Transittion: Fade
  (7) Action: pause on hover
  (8) Internet Explorer Tweaks: default
  (9) Widgets: You can choose either or both Top and Bottom (I choose bottom here, and the advance settings as below;)
  (10) Bottom Widgets>Pager>Pager type: Fields
  (11) Pager field: Content: Image (Note: last one we added for the thumb, don't mistake since both field will be named same.)
  (12) Activate Slide and Pause on Pager Hove: checked, controls and slider counter leave unchecked.
  (13) Click Apply button.

Format Show Field Settings

```
Inline fields: Choose the thumbnail field as inline.
Click Apply button. (Note: Well it actually doesn't change much in appearance but it does change in the code. Next step use the firebug and find the class and add some styles to display properly.)
```

(8) Create a Custom Region (optional step)

(1) On your thems folder open the your_theme_name.info file and add a new region like this shown below;
regions[featured_slider] = Featured Slider and save the .info file.
(2) Open your themes page.tpl.php file and add these code where you want your slide to be displayed as shown below;

You can even create custom front page template like page--front.tpl.php so that you do't need to make any changes to the default page.tpl.php template.
[9] Enable & configure the Block

Now this block will be visible in the blocks disabled area, so from the Dashboard menu go to Structure>Block and enable the block to a themes default region  or the custom region we created (featured_slider). (Regions varies depends on the theme you are using.)

Block Configuration Settings
After enabling the block you get a link to configure the block so click on the Configure link and on the settings section set as below;

(1) Block title (if you don't want blobk title to be displayed just type )
  (2) Again you get all enabled theme specific Region settings.
  On visibility setings
  (3) Pages>Show block on specific page: choose Only the listed pages and type  so that this block will be displayed only on the front page.
CSS TIPS TO DISPLAY THUMBNAILS INLINE

Add these CSS codes to your themes style sheet to display the thumbnails inline.
.views-slideshow-controls-bottom .views-slideshow-pager-field-item { float: left; margin: 20px 6px; } Make necessary adjustments.

Comment: I think the length of this (wonderful and thorough) post, may indicate why I'm so frustrated trying to learn drupal

Comment: Drupal is really easy and powerfull but from time to time you find something stupidly simple and it takes you 2 days to make it, and you have to digg in to the code  :/ Still my favourite CMS though

Comment: Oh by the way, I followed your tutorial from the begining to the end, and I only wish there was a way in stackexchange to upvote more than once. Lots of thanks dude, you really helped me out here !

Comment: I am glad it helped out. I have also created a Feature module that is currently being reviewed for release on Drupal.org. It packages up all of the steps I have outlined above, plus it goes one step further and makes it completely responsive and uses client side adaptive images for use in Themes like Omega. See http://drupal.org/sandbox/nicoz/1538528

Comment: Dinaiz, you can award more points by starting a bounty and then selecting "Reward existing answer" ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this Mustardseed Media podcast: [Views Slideshow Theming](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42).

During the podcast, Bob runs through some of the basics of Views Slideshow as well as how to theme the output.  It is based around Drupal 6, but I believe most of the basics and lessons will be the same.  With only a little CSS, a slideshow can look a *ton* better. I highly recommend watching this podcast if you want nice looking slideshows.

Comment: While this video may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/585/call-to-action-flag-any-answer-that-is-not-an-answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more of views slideshow (for example with thumbnails ) you must see this good tutorial:
http://www.brightwebsitedesign.com/how-to-install-views-slideshow-module-on-drupal7

Comment: This is the same article that @Nigel posted

Comment: I think that Nigel copy and pasted that page right into an answer :)  This is much more neat though, so I voted this up :)  I just got into the office a few minutes ago so I'm going to sit down and try to bang out this slideshow this morning.  I'll accept this if it works out.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so with all said and done I had actually already done most of what he told you to do in that tutorial.  He didn't really manipulate the paging in a manner which I hoped he would, though.  

Gonna have to do some serious CSS and jQuery hacking to make this work.